# Singletons and Pair Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are pair sets a consequence of singleton sets and a pairwise union? I'm using Tao's Analysis and though he states at the beginning of the chapter (chapter three, for reference) that some axioms in the book are redundant, he somewhat implies later on that the singleton/pair sets-axiom isn't.